# Jquery load script rather than call inline function

Tags: jquery

I'm not too great with jquery and maybe this title doesn't explain too well what i want to do but here goes:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my_action',
    dataType: 'script',
    beforeSend: function() { //can i not just call a script here instead?
        if (1 == 1) //just an example
        {
            return false
        }
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('DONE');
    }
});​
```

So in `beforeSend`, I want to call a script rather than have an inline function.  This is because my function is quite long and it makes the ajax code I have looks messy.

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *call a script*? Call another function or call a script from external file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your request as follows to load the external JavaScript file before Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my_action',
    dataType: 'script',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $.getScript("/path/to/script.js", function() {
            // you can call any function from the loaded file
            console.log('DONE');
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'my_action',
    dataType: 'script',
    beforeSend : foo // where foo is a function name.
```

Exmaple:

```
function foo(){
    // Do your magic here.
}
```

Comment: Basically, i make this ajax call via a php framework, and having loads of inline javascript in it looks ugly.  so i want to know a way to call either a function in a js file the app has access to, or call an extenral script rather than a function.  Thanks

Comment: yep they share the same scope your code works perfectly in that instance - thanks!

Comment: @rix. I don't get it, if they share the same scope why did you accept an answer why do you send an ajax request to load the script?